# Nested structure with the same name in C

Tags: c, nested, structure

I have a exercice that I have to realise a structure to match this line in C

```
int main() {
     t_foo foo;
     foo.foo.foo = 0;
     return (0);
}
```

I tried to create a nested structure, but I can't create with a same name. Have you an idea ?

Comment: Why don't you show us your attempt?

Comment: You can't nest (or redefine) the same struct *type*, but you can certainly have a member with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct a
{
    int foo;
};

struct c
{
    int d;
    struct a foo;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct c foo;

    foo.foo.foo = 2;
    printf("%d\n",foo.foo.foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can do that the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo
{
    struct
    {
        int foo;
    } foo;
} t_foo;


int main(void) 
{
    t_foo foo;
    foo.foo.foo = 0;

    printf( "%d\n", foo.foo.foo );

    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct foo
    {
        int foo;
    } foo;
} t_foo;


int main(void) 
{
    t_foo foo;
    foo.foo.foo = 0;

    printf( "%d\n", foo.foo.foo );

    return 0;
}
```